# How do I find Port wise active local connection

Tags: 14.04, networking, monitor

I am running Ubuntu system and I need to find port wise active local connection using any utility.

I try `iftop` utility but its showing only internet connection.

Comment: What does  "active" mean here?

Comment: Try `netstat -ntlp`

Comment: @munu  "active"  means connection is running stat, example someone using `5900` port on network and I need to identify them

Comment: @ThatGuy this showing internet connection also.

Comment: @Ravi - as muru said, your question is unclear. Are you trying to monitor traffic across a network? Or are you trying to monitor your own machine? Are you wanting to see incoming and outgoing traffic? So you want to know what applications are using which ports? I think you may need to be more specific.

Comment: @munu I've to monitor on my own pc and want to see incoming and outgoing traffic and if i pass port to find live traffic.

Comment: @Ravi lookup wireshark.